# How long are local push messages stored |ionic|cordova|angularjs|android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I'm making a timed push notification to remind customers of their service date.
(2 years from their purchase date)

I made a script where users can fill in their purchase date:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="data.userDate" ng-change="test()">
$scope.test = function() {
          var myDate = $scope.data.userDate;
          var notify = new Date(myDate);
          notify.setYear(myDate.getFullYear()+2);
          $scope.data.notify = notify;
        };
```

And let them ask for push messages using a button:

```
<button class="button button-full button-positive cta" ng-click="nextpage()">
$scope.nextpage = function(){
          if ($scope.data.notify > null){
            $state.go("app.notifysuccess"); 
            if ($scope.data.notify > null){
              cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
                id: 10,
                title: "Minnesma app",
                text: "Bel ons nu voor een onderhoudsbeurt!",
                at: $scope.data.notify,
                icon: "http://jurjenfolkertsma.nl/icon.png",
                data: { meetingId:"red" }
              });
            }
          }
          else {
            if($scope.data.notify == null){
              $scope.data.message = "Please vul eerst uw aankoopdatum in";
            }
            else{
              $scope.data.notify = "";
            }
          }
        }
```

It works with a delay of 1 day:

[image]

But now I'm wondering... would it still be stored after 1 year? Or after 2 years? Can I use this system for this? Or should I use another system to send custom timed push messages?

Comment: I had used it and it works until you exit application.

Comment: This is if you exit the application or if you uninstall it?

Comment: When exit the application. It only work when you press Home button. If you press Back button to exit, it will not work.

Comment: Is there any solution to fix this problem? and where do i need to look for?

Comment: You could give it a try with this link: http://red-folder.blogspot.com/2012/09/phonegap-service-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: This is made in java... i myself are a total java noob. is there any javascript way of doing this?

Comment: I have searched many times for javascript library but got no answer for this ^^